# `nanosleep()` async-signal safety on Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, signals, posix, ucontext

I need to use the `nanosleep` function in my user-space threads library to achieve waits of the approximately desired amount, as it can save the remaining time in case of an interrupt by async signals. I use SIGALRM to switch threads preemptively; therefore, it is important to consider the possible side effects of using non-reentrant functions. For that reason, in case a `nanosleep` call is interrupted by a thread switch and it is called again from another thread or signal handler, I wonder if this situation would cause problems or not.

Apparently, `nanosleep` function is not async-signal safe by [as it is not listed here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html); however, `sleep(3)` is said to be async-signal safe. On the other hand, [`sleep(3)` seems to be implemented using `nanosleep` on Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html). Can I take this as proof that `nanosleep` is safe for what I am trying to achieve?

EDIT: According to [this resource](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sleeping.html), it is indeed AS-safe.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't safely assume that unless it's specifically documented.  The reason is that using `nanosleep` is an implementation detail of `sleep`.  If the two functions were refactored to use some common internal function in glibc that were async-signal safe but `nanosleep`'s implementation changed such that it were not, your code would be broken.

You cannot rely on the implementation details of functions in glibc, since they can and do change across versions.  Notably, all Adobe Flash versions broke on certain machines because glibc changed `memcpy` to copy down instead of up, which is permitted by the standard and the documentation.

Also, just because glibc does things a certain way doesn't mean other Linux libcs do (or other non-Linux libcs), and your code wouldn't work there.

Comment: *copy down instead of up*... Was someone using `memcpy()` when they should have been using `memmove()` from the start on overlapping buffers?

Comment: Yes, they were doing exactly that. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=638477